# implement search function (filter) in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter, searchbar

I have a search bar where I type any letter/word. When that letter/word is found it is automatically displayed (without clicking on any particular key)
`

```
<div *ngFor="let car in cars | filter : searchText">
```

`
The problem is this: if I place between car and cars, it underlines the ngFor directive as an error, displaying the following error message:

> The *ngFor directive was used in the template, but neither the `NgFor`
> directive nor the `CommonModule` was imported. Please make sure that
> either the `NgFor` directive or the `CommonModule` is included in the
> `@Component.imports` array of this component.

I tried to import 'CommonModule' but it gives me the same error message. If, on the other hand, I try to write of between car and cars, it underlines the word filter as an error and displays me as an error:

> no pipe found with name 'filter'. I need to implement a simple search
> function

I expected typing this statement
`<div *ngFor="let car in cars | filter : searchText">`
the search method worked properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to import common module in angular to use the `*ngIf`, `*ngFor` and other directives:

Please refer the below line to import **Common Mondule** in Angular:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

Add it into your imports array in app.module.ts and you should got to go.
For further reading please find the Angular official documentation on Angular Common Module [here](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule)

And for the your second issue:

You need specify the name of your pipe properly.

**For example:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })

export class filter implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, character: any): string {
       // logic
    }

}
```

Whatever the name under name `@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })` should be representing in the usage template.

```
<div *ngFor="let car in cars | filter ">
```

Comment: Good. I did as you told me but it always tells me that no pipe function with that name was found. Naturally the pipe name specified in the pipe function and the function name specified in the html are the same

Comment: Can you provide the stackblitz or share me you screen if possible I would assist you via any media

Comment: unfortunately, this is company code. I can't do it due to privacy/confidentiality issues

Comment: I tried to leave you feedback but I get the following message "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."
Hope you can receive it asap. anyway thanks for everything

Comment: Can you break down the question and add another question to the second question so that I can give upvote for you

Comment: I couldn't do it. can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74655710/implement-search-function-filter-in-angular-part-2